# WPF Buttons disappear on 55" screen

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I developed a wpf-app with C# in Visual Studio 2017. 
When deploying the software on the target devices (55" NEC Touchscreens, Resolution 1920x1080) the buttons I designed will disappear when the app launches, while the rest of the MainWindow stays in place. I set in `<Window>` tag `Height="1080" Width="1920"`. When testing the software on my 1920x1080 screen on my desktop (22") the buttons were in place.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}" Click="QuickGuide_Click" Name="QuickGuide"  Background="#253135" Margin="375,531,1362,375">
        <TextBlock Text="Quick Guide" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="xyz" FontSize="12" Margin="0,59,0,58"/>
    </Button>
```

I have four Buttons, all with just different positions.

This is the whole XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Startup.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Prometheus" Height="1080" Width="1920"
    WindowState="Maximized"
WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"

    >
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resource/background_img.png"></ImageBrush>

</Window.Background>


<Grid Margin="12">





    <Grid Margin="10,4,-10,361" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.013,0.15" Name="GetEventsBtn" Click="GetEvents" Height="34" IsDefault="True" TabIndex="2" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,68,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hi" VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontFamily="" Height="60" Width="613" Foreground="#FFE0D2D2" FontSize="48"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please choose one option below to get started quickly." VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontFamily="" Height="46" Width="499" Foreground="#FFE0D2D2" FontSize="20"/>

    </Grid>




    <Button Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}" Click="QuickGuide_Click" Name="QuickGuide"  Background="#253135" Margin="375,531,1362,375">
        <TextBlock Text="Quick Guide" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="" FontSize="12" Margin="0,59,0,58"/>
    </Button>


    <Button  Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}"  Click="PlanAMeeting_Click" Name="PlanAMeeting"  Margin="170,531,1576,375">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Plan a meeting" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}" Click="CreateAMeeting_Click" Name="CreateAMeeting"  Margin="375,319,1362,587">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="" FontSize="12"> Create a new <LineBreak></LineBreak> meeting for now</TextBlock>
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}" Click="StartAMeeting_Click" Name="StartAMeeting"  Margin="170,319,1576,587">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="" FontSize="12">Start a scheduled<LineBreak></LineBreak>  meeting</TextBlock>
    </Button>

    <Grid MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="600" Margin="1147,-306,39,306" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="GR1Z1" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Text="Please wait while loading..."></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR1Z2" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR1Z3" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR1Z4" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="4"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR1Z5" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="5"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>

    <Grid MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="600" Margin="1147,96,39,306">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="GR2Z1" Grid.Row="1"  Foreground="White" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR2Z2" Grid.Row="2"  Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR2Z3" Grid.Row="3"  Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR2Z4" Grid.Row="4" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="GR2Z5" Grid.Row="5" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

and the style

```
  <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="FlatButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#253135"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#253135"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    CornerRadius="12"
                                Name="Border">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the target screen and your developer screen have different DPI settings?

Comment: little suggestion don't use Margin and check if your 55 screen is 100% scale in display setting

Comment: You shouldn't use Absolute position (Margin="#,#,#,#"), but relative positions if you want to achieve a dynamic layout. In particular you should contain the buttons into a grid and define the layout like this. If you post the whole XAML we can refactor it a little.

Comment: What about to remove `Margin`? is it shown? If it is, the problem is just position.

Comment: If you could post the `Style` for your `Button` then it will be easier for us to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to give you the idea:

- I removed all `Margin` properties, in order to not use an absolute position, but relative positions if you want to achieve a dynamic layout.
- I put your left part of the layout into a grid with three rows where the first two are for your headers text, and the last one for the buttons.
- In the last row I put another grid with two rows and two columns where each cell contains a buttons

This part of markup corresponds to the next grid after your: `<Grid Margin="12">`:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            FontSize="48"
            Foreground="#FFE0D2D2"
            Text="Hi"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            FontSize="20"
            Foreground="#FFE0D2D2"
            Text="Please choose one option below to get started quickly."
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button
                Name="QuickGuide"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Background="#253135"
                Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}">
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                    Text="Quick Guide"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Button>

            <Button
                Name="PlanAMeeting"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}">
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                    Text="Plan a meeting"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Button>

            <Button
                Name="StartAMeeting"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}">
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                    TextAlignment="Center"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Start a scheduled
                    <LineBreak />
                    meeting
                </TextBlock>
            </Button>

            <Button
                Name="CreateAMeeting"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}">
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Foreground="AntiqueWhite"
                    TextAlignment="Center">
                    Create a new
                    <LineBreak />
                    meeting for now
                </TextBlock>
            </Button>


        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: This is a great help to start working with relative positions! Thank you very much.